# Unit testing Rxjava observables that have a delay

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to be able to unit test an `Observable` that has a delayed emission, but without actually waiting for the delay time. Is there a way to do this?

I'm currently using a CountDownHatch to delay the assert, and that works fine, but increases the test run time.

Example:

```
val myObservable: PublishSubject<Boolean> = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()
fun myObservable(): Observable<Boolean> = myObservable.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

@Test
fun testMyObservable() {
    val testObservable = myObservable().test()
    myObservable.onNext(true)

    // val lock = CountDownLatch(1)
    // lock.await(3100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    testObservable.assertValue(true)
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I was able to come up with a complete solution thanks to @aaron-he's answer.

It uses a combination of `TestScheduler` to advance the time and also `RxJavaPlugins` to override the default scheduler with the testScheduler. This allowed testing the `myObservable()` function without modification or needing to pass in a `Scheduler`.

```
@Before
fun setUp() = RxJavaPlugins.reset()

@After
fun tearDown() = RxJavaPlugins.reset()

@Test
fun testMyObservable() {
    val testScheduler = TestScheduler()
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }

    val testObservable = myObservable().test()
    myObservable.onNext(true)

    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    testObservable.assertEmpty()
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    testObservable.assertValue(true)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[`TestScheduler`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/TestScheduler.html) is perfect for this. It has a handy method `advanceTimeBy(long, TimeUnit)` allows you to control the timing. And `Observable.delay` has an [overload method](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#delay-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-io.reactivex.Scheduler-) takes a `Scheduler`.

So just use the default `Scheduler.computation()` in the `myObservable` function, and use `TestScheduler` for unit testing.

Comment: Just googled this issue and got here.  Probably should have just asked it in Slack.  lol

Answer (score 1):

Found some strange behaviour of `PublishSubject` it need some time for subscribe, for example the test is failed:

```
private val scheduler = TestScheduler()
    @Test
    fun publishSubjectFailedTest() {
        val callback: DelayCallback = mock()

        val myPublishSubject: PublishSubject<Boolean> = PublishSubject.create()
        myPublishSubject
            .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(
                Consumer<Boolean> {
                    callback.onCalldown()
                },
                Consumer<Throwable> {

                },
                Action {

                }
            )
        myPublishSubject.onNext(true)
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        verify(callback, times(1)).onCalldown()
    }
```

But if we add a time of `scheduler` before call `onNext`, for example `scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)`
then the test will be success:

```
 @Test
    fun publishSubjectSuccessTest() {
        val callback: DelayCallback = mock()

        val myPublishSubject: PublishSubject<Boolean> = PublishSubject.create()
        myPublishSubject
            .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(
                Consumer<Boolean> {
                    callback.onCalldown()
                },
                Consumer<Throwable> {

                },
                Action {

                }
            )
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)//added time of scheduler
        myPublishSubject.onNext(true)
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        verify(callback, times(1)).onCalldown()
    }
```