# Testing Rx Java interval

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a repeated observable inside a ViewModel as below:

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val ratesUseCase: RatesUseCase) : ViewModel() {

    private var disposable: Disposable? = null
    private val resultLiveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<Map<String, Double>>>()

    fun result() = resultLiveData
    fun getRates(base: String) {
        disposable = Observable
            .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap { ratesUseCase.execute(base) }
            .doOnSubscribe { publishResult(Resource.loading(mapOf())) }
            .subscribe(
                {
                    publishResult(Resource.success(values))
                },
                {
                    publishResult(Resource.error(it.localizedMessage, mapOf()))
                }
            )
    }

}
```

I want to test getRates function. It always return LOADING status 
What is missing here?

Test case :

```
@Test
    fun executeSuccess() {
        val base = "CANARY"
        whenever(currencyRepository.getRates(base))
            .thenReturn(Observable.just(map))

        viewModel.result().observeForever(observer)
        viewModel.getRates(base)
        verify(observer).onChanged(Resource.success(map))
    }
```

Comment: Did you override the scheduler in which Interval runs on?

Comment: Yes! like this `subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()).observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())`

Comment: Well, by default, interval runs on the computation thread. You should be able to set new schedulers for tests using the RxJavaPlugins APIs. Use setInitComputationSchedulerHandler to route everything running on the computation Scheduler to the trampoline() Scheduler.

Comment: Now I have them Injected. Interval now runs on  `Schedulers.trampoline()`  `Observable
         .interval(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS).compose(appSchedulers.observableTransformer())` but still give the same result

Comment: Oh, I see. Did you try debugging onNext and onComplete to see if they are actually running in sequence? This is very odd. Also, you're also running the InstantTaskExecutorRule, right?

Comment: Yes I do use the rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats what happens if you don't pass `Scheduler` to `Observable.interval`.

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.COMPUTATION)
public static Observable<Long> interval(long period, TimeUnit unit) {
    return interval(period, period, unit, Schedulers.computation());
}
```

It will use `Schedulers.computation()` as default Scheduler.

Your test thread will just finish while `interval` will not manage to emit anything.

You have to you use `TestScheduler` to test interval properly.
See here:
[Unit testing Rxjava observables that have a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296993/unit-testing-rxjava-observables-that-have-a-delay)

You can override computation scheduler or pass `TestScheduler` to `Observable.interval` in your ViewModel.
Then you can `TestScheduler.advanceTimeBy` and control your interval emissions.

Answer (score 6):

I did fix the tests here is how I did it.
there are two observable here:

1- Observable with `interval()` of `1` second.

2- Observable of `ratesUseCase.execute(base)`.
as you can see below this how is it inside the `MainViewModel`

```
        Observable
        .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .flatMap { ratesUseCase.execute(base) }
        .doOnSubscribe { publishResult(Resource.loading(mapOf())) }
        .subscribe(
            {
                publishResult(Resource.success(values))
            },
            {
                publishResult(Resource.error(it.localizedMessage, mapOf()))
            }
        )
```

To test `getRates` in `MainViewModel`

1- Inject Test schedulers for `ratesUseCase.execute(base)`

2- Use `RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler` to change the default Scheduler as below

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    val testScheduler = TestScheduler()
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }

    ratesUseCase = RatesUseCase(appSchedulers, currencyRepository)
    viewModel = MainViewModel(ratesUseCase)
}
```

3- Use `testScheduler.advanceTimeTo` to test `interval`. Please not the order here is important as below:

3.a : Mock repository

3.b : Observe ViewModel LiveData

3.c : Advance Time interval

3.d : Verify result

```
    val base = "BASE"
    whenever(currencyRepository.getRates(base))
        .thenReturn(Observable.just(map))

    viewModel.result().observeForever(observer)
    viewModel.getRates(base)

    testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    verify(observer).onChanged(
        Resource.success(map)
    )
```

Full project and test cases can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/epardus/currency/src/master/)